# no-op function template

Tags: c++, templates

I need to implement a no-op in C++ which preserves all type extensions (const, rvalue ref, lvalue ref). Can I do this as follows?

```
template<class T>
T && noop (T && t) { return std::forward<T> (t); }
```

and call it like

```
... noop (value) ...
```

(i.e. use type inference)? I.e. does `noop (value)` have exactly the same type as `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. However, it's no different from just calling std::forward in the client code itself (except that with std::forward there's no automatic template argument deduction).

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, why not just call `std::forward` to begin with...

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe `noop` is used under the covers of a larger system as one of many possible implementations of a particular operation (i.e. do stuff under some conditions, `noop` under others).

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to become one of a `template<class T> f (T && t, std::false_type) { ... }`, `template<class T> f (T && t, std::true_type) { ... }` pair of functions.